# cannot borrow `self` as immutable because `self.chars` is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust

I need immutable access to one struct field and mutable access to another one, but they have to be stacked on each other. I've had this problem multiple times and I don't know how to fix this.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Bar;
impl Bar {
    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        100
    }
}
struct Foo {
    chars: HashMap<char, i32>,
    b: Bar,
}

impl Foo {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        self.chars.entry('c').or_insert_with(|| self.b.get() * 100);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = Foo {
        chars: HashMap::new(),
        b: Bar,
    };
    m.run();
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self` as immutable because `self.chars` is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:16:46
   |
16 |         self.chars.entry('c').or_insert_with(|| self.b.get() * 100);
   |         ----------                           ^^ ----              - mutable borrow ends here
   |         |                                    |  |
   |         |                                    |  borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
   |         |                                    immutable borrow occurs here
   |         mutable borrow occurs here
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're trying to borrow `self` mutably *and* immutably, as the compiler says. As [pointed out by Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515301/cannot-borrow-self-as-immutable-because-self-chars-is-also-borrowed-as-mutab#comment84026005_48515883), the borrow checker can't distinguish access to fields across closure boundaries, so we need to help it a bit by being more explicit about what we want to borrow and pass to the closure.

A way to do this is to take out a reference to `self.b` and use that inside the `or_insert_with()`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Bar;
impl Bar {
    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        100
    }
}
struct Foo {
    chars: HashMap<char, i32>,
    b: Bar,
}

impl Foo {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        let b = &self.b;
        self.chars.entry('c').or_insert_with(|| b.get() * 100);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = Foo {
        chars: HashMap::new(),
        b: Bar,
    };
    m.run();
}
```

Comment: Maybe also explain what the problem is: "The borrow checker can distinguish access to different fields, but not across function/closure boundaries.  If you use `self` in the closure, it will borrow `self`, not just the field you're trying to access in the closure".

Comment: @Stefan fair point. Added some context, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Well explained. Thank you!